# What is the significance of number 3 in Islam?

Tags: mythology

What is the significance of number 3 in Islam ?

Comment: Where did you hear about this?

Comment: May be you're looking for this... [Allah loves odd numbers](http://www.hadithcollection.com/sahihmuslim/163-Sahih%20Muslim%20Book%2035.%20The%20Rememberance%20Of%20Allah,%20Supplication,%20Repentance%20And%20Seeking%20Forgiveness/14808-sahih-muslim-book-035-hadith-number-6476.html) If the situation is pertaining to bearing witnesses then it would be kalahari's answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it is specifically used only in marriage & divorce issues. The role of 3 in these is to make sure that the responsible has clearly and constantly said to agree and everyone could heard him/her. Also it was not a word mistakenly spoken, the one who said it was actually aware of what he/she is agreeing.